# When the user closes the announcement don't show notification to user again

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, notifications

I have created a notification bar on my site that I don't want to be shown to users again on subsequent visits after they close it the first time. The bar works as expected, but I can't seem to get the cookie to work to not display it again

##### js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".m-close").click(function(){
      $(".m-bar").hide(600);
  });
});
```

##### html code

```
<center>
  <div class="m-bar m-red">
    <a class="m-microphone"><i class="material-icons" style="font-size:26px;">mic</i></a>
    <a class="m-content" style="color: white;">Something Text</a>
    <a class="m-close" href="#"><i class="material-icons">close</i></a>
  </div>
</center> <br><br>
```

Comment: Use a cookie or local storage to remember if you've showed it before.

Comment: I don't know how to do this can you show me?

Comment: I'll write something that may help you, give me a few minutes

Comment: I'm waiting thx

Comment: I want to send announcements to users from time to time

Comment: Here, I posted an answer, let me know if you have any issues! Also all of my code is done in vanilla JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a code example:

```js
function addCookie(name, value, days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
}

function getCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

// When clicking the close button
addCookie('hidden', 'yes', 30);

// Checks if the user chose to hide the announcement
const isHidden = getCookie('hidden');

if (isHidden == 'yes') {
   // Hide the announcement
   $(".m-bar").hide(600);
}
else {
   // Show the announcement
   // ...
}
```

First you can use the `addCookie()` function to add a cookie when you close the announcement.

After that when you display the announcement, check if the cookie `hidden` is set to yes, if it is set to `yes` then hide the announcement, otherwise show it.

Also of course you can use different names and values and expiration dates for your cookies, I recommend setting a long expiration date.

Comment: where should i paste this code

Comment: sorry my coding knowledge is poor i am in learning phase

Comment: Everything is included in the post, add the functions anywhere. Then create a variable like shown above for the hidden cookie and use `if` and `else` to check if the cookie is already set, if not then set the cookie using the `addCookie()` like shown above. Now copy the code that shows your announcement and create another `if` statement that checks if the variable of the cookie you created is set to yes. If it's yes then hide the announcement like you did in your original code else show the announcement.

Comment: You know about the `if` and `else` statements right?

Comment: Can you combine all of these with my codes and post them here?

Comment: You must give me all your code, also please comment the parts of code I'm going to work with

Comment: I already sent the js file. This is the index.blade.php file


```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div class="duyuru" style="text-align: center;">
  <div class="m-bar m-red">
    <a class="m-microphone"><i class="material-icons" style="font-size:26px;">mic</i></a>
    <a class="m-content" style="color: white;">Text</a>
    <a class="m-close" href="#" onClick="hideAnnouncement()"><i class="material-icons">close</i></a>
  </div>
</div> <br><br>

@endsection('content')
```

Comment: I added the codes js file, this time the announcement appears and disappears

Comment: Edit your post. Don't send code in comments.

Comment: can you explain in detail

Comment: What..? Just edit your post and include all your code

Comment: else {
   // Show the announcement
   // ...
}

I don't know what to write in this part

Answer (score 0):

I don´t choose use a Cookie for this, I will use the localStorage because is a simple notification:

```
$(window).on('load', function(){

    //Create a variable for localStorage return
    var confirm = {
        notification: false
    };

    //Get the Data from localStorage
    let dataconfirm = localStorage.getItem('confirm');

    if(dataconfirm != null){

        confirm.notification = dataconfirm;

    }

    console.log(confirm);
  
    $(document).ready(function(){
 

     $('form').on('click', function(e){

        e.preventDefault();

        if(!confirm.notification === true){

            localStorage.setItem('confirm', true);

        }


     });   

  
    });
  
  
  });
```